# Linebreaks in labels after PDF export

Tags: export, pdf-format

This just drives me crazy: Suppose I have a label `label` that I want to put on top of a `Graphics` (or any other *Mathematica* object like a `Grid`).

```
label= Style[ "This is just some text for a label that is not too wide.", "Label", 18];
size = {600, 200};
plot = Labeled[Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> size, Background -> LightBlue], label, {{Top, Center}}]
```

This is what *Mathematica* 12.0 on macos shows to me in the notebook:

[image]

This is what I get after export to PDF:

```
First@ImportString[ExportString[plot, "PDF"], "PDF"]
```

[image]

Not only doesn't this keep the size of the `Labeled` region, what really annoys me is the linebreak in the label.

Does anybody know how to prevent that?

PS.: I *know* that I could use the `PlotLabel` option of `Graphics`. The `Graphics` object here is really only a place holder.

Comment: in V 12.1 I do not see this. Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hgkzU.png)

Comment: Thank you, @Nasser, that gives me hope for the future! =)

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem on V 12.0 on Win 10.

Comment: Thank you Chris. That underlines my suspicion that it is related to the way macos handles PDF. That changed frequently and caused many problems in the past.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this appears to be a version and os-specific issue. So in my desperate attempts I recalled the old $\LaTeX$ rule to make a box around everything. What comes closest to a box is an invisible frame. And indeed  `Framed` allows for an `ImageSize` option, leading to this workaround:

```
plot = Labeled[
   Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> size, Background -> LightBlue],
   Framed[label, ImageSize -> {size[[1]], Automatic}, 
    Alignment -> Center, FrameStyle -> None],
   {{Top, Center}}
   ];
First@ImportString[ExportString[plot, "PDF"], "PDF"]
```

[image]